# Issue Enabling Kernel Livepatch on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, canonical-livepatch

I am currently facing an issue with enabling Kernel Livepatch on Ubuntu 22.04. I have attempted to disable and re-enable Livepatch multiple times, but each time I receive the error message "Could not enable Livepatch. Please try again."

Here is the output of the command "sudo pro status" that shows the status of Ubuntu Pro:

```
SERVICE          ENTITLED  STATUS    DESCRIPTION
esm-apps         yes       enabled   Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications
esm-infra        yes       enabled   Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure
livepatch        yes       warning   Current kernel is not supported
realtime-kernel  yes       disabled  Ubuntu kernel with PREEMPT_RT patches integrated
usg              yes       disabled  Security compliance and audit tools

NOTICES
The current kernel (5.19.0-45-generic, amd64) is not supported by livepatch.
Supported kernels are listed here: https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/kernels
Either switch to a supported kernel or `pro disable livepatch` to dismiss this warning.

Enable services with: pro enable <service>

Account: ***********@*****.com
Subscription: Ubuntu Pro - free personal subscription
```

I initially used a supported kernel version (22.04.02), but I encountered this problem. Even after reinstalling Ubuntu multiple times, I still face the same error.

[image: Issue Pic]

Comment: It's right there in your output: `Supported kernels are listed here: https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/kernels`. That list does not include your current kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS currently supports *livepatch* only on the GA kernel stack (ie. 5.15).

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS will commence support on the HWE kernel stack standard with the 6.2 kernel (from Ubuntu 23.04), but that's not available yet (ETA is July 2023).

Please refer https://ubuntu.com/blog/canonical-livepatch-gets-even-better-now-supporting-hardware-enablement-kernels

> We’ve listened to your feedback and are pleased to announce that
> Livepatch will now be available on HWE kernels. This will debut with
> the release of kernel version 6.2, which will initially accompany
> Ubuntu’s interim release of 23.04 Lunar Lobster, in April 2023.
> Thereafter, it will be made accessible as an HWE kernel for the 22.04
> LTS release, Jammy Jellyfish, **starting July 2023**.

( *emphasis added* )

Comment: FYI:  The 6.2 kernel (from 23.04) is on its way `linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04-edge | 6.2.0.23.23~22.04.4   | jammy-proposed   | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x` *having been there a day or two as I noticed it before today*